# Show $g=3$ is contained in the unit ball of $X=C[0,1]$ in the uniform metric.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

How do I show that the function $g=3$ is contained in the unit ball of $X=C[0,1]$ in the uniform metric?

I know the uniform metric $$d_u(g,0)=sup |3|$$ where do I go after this?

Comment: The result is wrong. The distance of the constant function $g$ always equal to $3$ to the origin is equal to $3$. Hence $g$ does not belong to the unit ball.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot show this as it is not true. Based on your definition of distance given $g$ is distance $3$ away from $0$ because $\sup\vert 3\vert=3$. The definition of the unit ball is things with distance less than or equal to $1$ from $0$. As $3>1$, $g$ is not contained in the unit ball.

Comment: I have [edit]ed your post to improve its readabilty by introducing MathJaX. MathJaX is used to write maths on this site. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?lq=1) you can find a basic tutorial.